# VBA: AddDate + time changes the format

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone advise, please?

I have used `DateSerial`, `DateValue` with mixed results, also `Format(`... doesn't work in this case.

When I use `DateAdd("d", 1, DateValue(x.Value))`

```
06/05/2021  20:20:20
```

is changed to

```
05/07/2021 20:20:20
```

All I need is this `06/05/2021  20:20:20` to be changed to this `07/05/2021  20:20:20`

FYI if it helps the format of my cells is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Where is `x` coming from? Is that a cell?

Comment: @braX Yes, x is a cell

Comment: I've never had to use `DateValue` or `DateSerial` for anything like this, but my system settings are USA so the month is first. Someone else might have a better answer, but until then, try using `CDate` to convert the cell to a date variable that you can check before adding the day, then just add the day to that. That way you know if the problem is coming from the date conversion or the part where it's adding a day. Also check your system settings for how dates are handled.

Comment: `x.Value + 1` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and swap dd/mm to mm/dd (the format will remain dd/mm/yyyy):

Format(DateAdd("d", 1, cel.Value), "mm/dd/yyyy") & " 18:59:59"

Comment: I don't get how this works but it does. The format stays indeed the same (when I check through right-clicking on a cell and formats) yet the day appears first as it should! Is there an issue with MS Office that one needs to "trick it" into believing something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use `DateAdd`, and your value is a true date value (not text), use:

```
DateAdd("d", 1, x.Value)
```

This will not alter a time part. If x is `2021-05-06 20:20:20`, result will be:

```
`2021-05-07 20:20:20`
```

If x is `2021-05-06 18:59:59` you can add one hour:

```
DateAdd("h", 1, x.Value)
```

for the result: `2021-05-06 19:59:59`

Comment: Gustav, thank you, it works. However, is there a way to add a day to the date but make sure that the time hh:mm:ss is e.g. (not 20:20:20) 18:59:59? When I do it at the moment it simply gives me two-time frames like this (and if I use "Format(" the dates are swapped again) Then cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, cel.Value) & " 18:59:59" (result: 07/05/2021 20:20:20 18:59:59). (DateAdd "h" is not what I need I think)

Comment: A date value has no format. Format is for display only. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

just `x.value + 1` it'll get that it's a date and add one day

Comment: Hi Daniel, sadly it has generated the same issue - changed formats. Gustav's result made it work - please see the comment I have left under Gustav's answer. Perhaps you can help and edit your answer? Much obliged